# How would I be able to take in Rich Text from a user on a Web Page, store that rich text, and then output the stored rich text into a Word Document?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently, I'm using a page which utilizes a WYSIWYG editor (SummerNote) to allow me to extract the Rich Text which is copy pasted into the editor (the user will basically copy in anything from a word document to it). This is then output as a html string, which I can then convert back to RTF using SautinSoft.HtmlToRtf, however, this does not output exactly the original Rich Text content that was pasted into the editor.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to deal with this or tools available for this?

Comment: once the text is pasted into the editor, at that point it's converted to HTML already, I think it's already gone, swallowed by the editor. Anyway what's the point of a process which just returns exactly what was put into it?

Comment: No two web browsers in the known Universe can agree how to display a HTML page so the possibility of outputting correct RTF is highly unlikely

Comment: I've changed the way we are dealing with the problem at hand. Summer Note wasn't giving us what we wanted and we took note of a few limitations with regards to Rich Text Editors. 

Basically now just going the route of Rich Text Editor -> Store HTML -> Parse Html into OpenXML and populate a word document with that. Seems to be the only solid way about taking rich text from an editor and putting it into a word document